# Separation of variables for the time-independent Schrödinger equation in 2 dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Suppose I have a particle in an infinite potential 2D well
$$
V(x,y) = \begin{cases}0 & \mathrm{if}\ 0<x<a, \  0<y<b \\ \infty & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}
$$
Now if I assume that $\Psi(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$,
I understand why I get
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi(x,y)=E \Psi (x,y)$$
and, after some derivations,
$$\frac{f''}{f}+\frac{g''}{g}=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}.$$

However, what I don't understand is why, if their sum is equal to a constant, then each one of them has to be equal to a constant, and then solve 2 equations.

Answer (score 7):

$f''(x)/f(x)$ is dependent only on $x$ while $g''(y)/g(y)$ is dependent only on $y$. Nevertheless, the sum of these two terms is constant *for all values of $x$ and $y$*. This is possible only if each of the terms is constant, since otherwise their sum could be changed by varying one of the variables, while keeping the other constant.

**Remark**  The technique in question is called *separation of variables*. It is a well established approach in solving linear partial differential equations, of which Schrödinger equation is an example. Note that obtaining a time-independent Schrödinger equations similarly requires separating spatial variables and time.

Comment: can we just say that if $a$ is a function of $x$ and $b$ is a function of y and $a+b=d$ constant then if we will derive this equation with respect to x and with respect to y we will get $a'(x)=0$ and $b'(x)=0$ meaning that each one of them has to be constant?

Comment: It is possible to formulate it this way, but it is actually over complicating the things. It is a much more general statement, which does not require that the functions be differentiable etc.

Comment: If we have a(x) + b(y) = c, where c is constant for any x and y. Then if you vary x, c wont change. Same if you vary y. If a(x) is not constant, then changing x will change c, which we said doesn't happen. Same for b(y). Thus, a(x) and b(x) are both constant themselves.

Comment: "It is a well established approach in solving partial differential equations". **Linear** PDEs, to be specific.

Comment: @Gert true. I corrected it.